# Возможно ли ставить Safe Area в XIB

Tags: ios, swift

Я обновляю проект до swift 4, и мне необходимо сделать адаптацию под iphone X для моих `UIView`. Как возможно добавить safe area в мои `UIVIew`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался вставить safe area через простое копирование, к сожалению не удалось...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не в той вкладке смотрите :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Премного благодарен!